# How to completely disable SELinux in Android L in the init.rc file?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, selinux

I want to disable SELinux at boot time for Android L or 5. The reason is because my daemon is not begin executed on boot when it should due to SELinux problems. I have the following in my **init.rc** file:

```
su 0 setenforce 0
service my_daemon /system/bin/my_daemon 
    class main     # Also tried: class core (but it didn't make a difference)
    user root
    group root
```

However, on boot, I use adb shell to check if SELinux is disabled (using `getenforce`) and it returns `Enforcing`. I want SELinux to be completely disabled on boot. If not completely disabled then at least `Permissive`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

> setenforce 0

the enforce attribute will be Permissive imeddiately.

Comment: Looks like it's not that simple. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31147475/4449456

Comment: Yes. It depends on the root and the ROM. The above link is more complete.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of putting in init.rc you can make it permissive by adding some parameters to kernel command line (BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE)

Ex: Add `enforcing=0 androidboot.selinux=permissive` in `device/<manufacturer>/<target>/BoardConfig.mk`

Comment: What <manufacturer>/<target> would use use when building for the emulator? ro.hardware is "ranchu", if that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Well I guess you could create a new domain policy for your "my_daemon". For example, you can create mydomain.te file at device/manufacturer/device-name/sepolicy/ of your AOSP, with the following contents,

```
# mydomain policy here
type mydomain, domain;
permissive mydomain;
type mydomain_exec, exec_type, file_type;

init_daemon_domain(mydomain)
```

Now Add the following line to device/manufacturer/device-name/sepolicy/file_contexts:

```
/system/bin/my_daemon   u:object_r:mydomain_exec:s0
```

Here is your init.rc file:

```
service my_daemon /system/bin/my_daemon
    class core
```

So the good thing here is that only mydomain will be permissive and rest of the system will be enforcing, thus you can have your daemon running without any problems and still maintaining the system security.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling SElinux [only works](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/selinux/validate?hl=en) on `userdebug` or `eng` builds, not on standard `user` builds:

> Caution: Permissive mode is not supported on production devices. CTS tests confirm enforcing mode is enabled.
>
> SELinux enforcement can be disabled via ADB on userdebug or eng builds.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32660547/282601

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely disable SElinux, you need to change the selinux.cpp functions placed at `system/core/init`. Two functions `StatusFromProperty()` and `IsEnforcing()` set the status of the SElinux which are called in different units. If you change the value of return for both as `SELINUX_PERMISSIVE` and `false`, the SElinux status always will be permissive. Please see this answer related to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77497503/producing-a-user-build-of-aosp-with-permissive-selinux-policy). This also works for `user` type builds.