# How can we disable/remove SELinux during complie on Qualcomm platform?

Tags: android, selinux, qualcomm

I'm Qualcomm platform developer;

How can we disable/**remove** SELinux feature from software image during compiling? In a word,I need remove the SELinux feature from android

BTW:

`set setenforce 0` or `set getenforce` works well;

Comment: `mv  Android.mk Android.mk.bak `(external/libselinux/), than, **make -j16**; **unfortunately** an error occur  **make: *** No rule to make target `NOTICE-HOST-STATIC_LIBRARIES-libselinux', needed by `out/host/linux-x86/bin/fastboot'.  Stop**

Comment: By remove, do you mean remove and enable it again after you compile your software, I hope? Something like this might work assuming you have root:
'
su
printf '\x00' | su -c dd of=/dev/kmem seek=$( printf '%d\n' '0x'`cat /proc/kallsyms | grep ".*\ selinux\_enforcing" | cut -f 1 -d " "` ) bs=1 count=1 conv=notrunc'     or see this.. not sure what exactly you're trying to do.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2765353

Comment: @Chev_603 ,I mean remove the SELinux feature(remove); NOT enable it again.

Comment: You can disable it in the kernel. It's just like any other linux kernel. See this thead too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998343/how-to-set-selinux-to-0-or-permissive-mode-in-android-4-4-4-and-above

Comment: And certaintly you can set it to permissive as an alternative.  I mean, is that an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebuild the kernel with `CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX=n`. This is found in the kernel defconfig for your platform.

For example, to completely disable SELinux in the hammerhead (Nexus 5) kernel, change `arch/arm/configs/hammerhead_defconfig` per above and rebuild the kernel. Include this new kernel in your boot image and the result will be a device without any SELinux support at all. `getenforce` will return `Disabled`.