# Run shell script at boot in AOSP

Tags: android, linux, android-source, arm64

I am using iMX 8 Mini EVK for my Project. I build Android 9.0 from AOSP for this board.
Now I want to run a script at boot.
I did following changes in files but still, I am facing an issue.

**File : Android_AOSP_build/device/fsl/imx8m/evk_8mm/init.rc**

```
service gea3appservice /vendor/bin/sh /vendor/bin/run.sh 
  class late_start
  user root system
  group root system
  oneshot
```

**File : Android_AOSP_build/device/fsl/imx8m/evk_8mm/sepolicy/gea3appservice.te**

```
type gea3appservice, domain;
type gea3appservice_exec, exec_type, vendor_file_type, file_type;

init_daemon_domain(gea3appservice)

domain_auto_trans(init, vendor_shell_exec, gea3appservice)
```

**File : Android_AOSP_build/device/fsl/imx8m/evk_8mm/sepolicy/file_contexts**

```
/vendor/bin/run.sh   u:object_r:gea3appservice_exec:s0
```

When I manually run service I get following error :

> [  134.010656] type=1400 audit(1564667688.236:3740): avc: denied { dac_read_search } for pid=1 comm="init" capability=2 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=capability permissive=1

Does anyone know this issue?

I tried with the approach suggested by the Android developer site

https://source.android.com/security/selinux/device-policy

But I get the following error

> libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 1002 of system/sepolicy/public/domain.te (or line 11242 of policy.conf) violated by allow gea3appservice gea3appservice_exec:file { execute entrypoint };

Comment: What are the DAC (`chmod`) file permissions of `/vendor/bin/run.sh `?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root shell 503 2019-08-02 12:29 run.sh

Comment: @Abhijit , I am also facing the same prob with the Adnroid12 device. Have you got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

in init.mydevice.rc i have

```
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    start init-myservice-sh

service init-myservice-sh /vendor/bin/init.myscript.sh
    class main
    user root
    group root system
    disabled
    oneshot
```

and this is init.myscript.sh

```
#!/system/bin/sh

echo '#################  It works  ##################'
cd /system/app
ls -hal
```

in device/myvendor/mydevice/sepolicy folder i have file_contexts with

```
/vendor/bin/init\.myscript\.sh      u:object_r:init-myservice_exec:s0
```

and init-myservice.te

```
type init-myservice, domain;
type init-myservice_exec, exec_type, vendor_file_type, file_type;

init_daemon_domain(init-myservice)

allow init-myservice vendor_shell_exec:file rx_file_perms;
allow init-myservice vendor_toolbox_exec:file rx_file_perms;
```

of course you have to copy your script to the bin dir

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
 $(LOCAL_PATH)/init.myscript.sh:$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_VENDOR)/bin/init.myscript.sh
```

and in BoardConfig.mk

```
BOARD_SEPOLICY_DIRS := device/myvendor/mydevice/sepolicy
```

in my console i can see this

```
console:/ $ dmesg | grep myservice                                             
[   21.098013] init: starting service 'init-myservice-sh'...
[   21.148562] init: Command 'start init-myservice-sh' action=sys.boot_completed=1 (/vendor/etc/init/hw/init.mydevice.rc:66) took 51ms and succeeded
```

and try this

```
console:/ $ init.myscript.sh
#################  It works  ##################
```

for moor details see this article https://source.android.com/security/selinux/device-policy#label_new_services_and_address_denials

Comment: Doesn't work for Android 10:

avc: denied { map } for comm="init.myservice" path="/system/bin/sh" dev="dm-6" ino=872 scontext=u:r:init_myservice:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:shell_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

Comment: I can get it to work on android 10 by using /vendor/bin/sh instead of /system/bin/sh.  That will execute a basic script.  Unfortunately, my script needs to execute other commands found in /system/bin (Like am.. to start an activity), I still get denials an those and neverallow build errors if I try to allow access.

Comment: I am also facing the same prob with the Adnroid12 device. Have you got any solution? –

Answer (score 0):

The failed neverallow rule could indicate that your script tried to run a binary in `/system`, which is not allowed by a script located in `/vendor` according to the rule in [system/sepolicy/public/domain.te](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/refs/heads/pie-release/public/domain.te#1002).

> Do not allow vendor components to execute files from system
>    except for the ones whitelist here.

Comment: I checked by moving my script(**run.sh**) into **/system** directory but still i am facing same issue.

Comment: You mentioned two error messages in your question. One error before you tried something from source.android.com and a second error after that. About which error are we talking?

Comment: [ 134.010656] type=1400 audit(1564667688.236:3740): avc: denied { dac_read_search } for pid=1 comm="init" capability=2 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=capability permissive=1

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Is `init` the proper user or is it part of the proper group to access `/vendor/bin/sh`?

Comment: I am also facing the same prob with the Adnroid12 device. Have you got any solution?