# Run shell script at bootup in AOSP12 (aosp)

Tags: shell, android-source, selinux, android-12, rc

I have followed the below link to run the shell script in device bootup time.

[Run shell script at boot in AOSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370029/run-shell-script-at-boot-in-aosp).

Snipped error logs below :

```
console:/ $ dmesg | grep myservice
                                         
[   18.901774] type=1400 audit(1663315885.863:30): avc: denied { map } for comm="init.myscript.s" path="/system/bin/sh" dev="dm-0" ino=1401 scontext=u:r:init-myservice:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:shell_exec:s0 tclass=file permis
sive=1

[   18.902467] type=1400 audit(1663315885.863:31): avc: denied { read } for comm="init.myscript.s" path="/system/bin/sh" dev="dm-0" ino=1401 scontext=u:r:init-myservice:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:shell_exec:s0 tclass=file permi
ssive=1

[   18.902659] type=1400 audit(1663315885.863:32): avc: denied { execute } for comm="init.myscript.s" path="/system/bin/sh" dev="dm-0" ino=1401 scontext=u:r:init-myservice:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:shell_exec:s0 tclass=file pe
rmissive=1

[   18.902978] type=1400 audit(1663315885.866:33): avc: denied { getattr } for comm="init.myscript.s" path="/system/bin/sh" dev="dm-0" ino=1401 scontext=u:r:init-myservice:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:shell_exec:s0 tclass=file pe
rmissive=1

[   18.917293] type=1400 audit(1663315885.880:34): avc: denied { getattr } for comm="init.myscript.s" path="/system/bin/toybox" dev="dm-0" ino=1453 scontext=u:r:init-myservice:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:toolbox_exec:s0 tclass=f
ile permissive=1
[   18.917585] type=1400 audit(1663315885.880:35): avc: denied { execute } for comm="init.myscript.s" name="toybox" dev="dm-0" ino=1453 scontext=u:r:init-myservice:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:toolbox_exec:s0 tclass=file permissi
ve=1
[   18.925784] type=1400 audit(1663315885.886:36): avc: denied { execute } for comm="init.myscript.s" name="toybox" dev="dm-0" ino=1453 scontext=u:r:init-myservice:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:toolbox_exec:s0 tclass=file permissi
ve=1

[   18.928297] type=1400 audit(1663315885.886:37): avc: denied { read open } for comm="init.myscript.s" path="/system/bin/toybox" dev="dm-0" ino=1453 scontext=u:r:init-myservice:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:toolbox_exec:s0 tclass
=file permissive=1
[   18.928654] type=1400 audit(1663315885.890:38): avc: denied { execute_no_trans } for comm="init.myscript.s" path="/system/bin/toybox" dev="dm-0" ino=1453 scontext=u:r:init-myservice:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:toolbox_exec:s0
tclass=file permissive=1
console:/ $ [  787.013956] healthd: battery l=50 v=3 t=2.6 h=2 st=3 fc=100 chg=au
```

Can you please help to run the shell script in device bootup time .